# Why does Grammarly say "arrive IN class" but "arrive AT the store"?

Tags: prepositions

> What time did you arrive **at** class?
> What time did you arrive **to** class?

I looked up a grammar question and the top "at" sentence is what one of the users wrote in the comments. I think the first sentence is right but it sounds weird when I say it so I'm not sure. **Grammarly's telling me to change the prepositions "at" and "to" to "in"! Is it right?**

> What time did you arrive at the store?
> What time did you arrive to the store?

"At the store" sounds right to me, and even Grammarly's saying to change "to" in the 2nd sentence to "at" but **what's the difference between this one and the classroom one? Why do I have to put "in" for class but for the store it's optional?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *arrive to* is ever grammatical, unless you use *to* as an infinitive: *At what time did you arrive to say bon voyage?*

I think Grammerly is using *class* in relation to school.  You're *at* school but *in* class.  So, you don't arrive *at* class but *in* class.  When faced with a preposition quandary like this, try rephrasing.  "In/at...by" is a good substitute for "arrive".

"By what time were you *in* class/*at* the store/*in* the store/*at* the airport/*in* the lounge?"  You've not changed the sense but avoided the preposition mess.